Two German soldiers with a captive in a country house
I'm looking for a war movie, released in 2012 or later. The actors were low-profile.
Two German soldiers had captured a Finn or Dutchman. The German commander was a good boy.
They're in the woods and everything is covered in snow. They arrive at a house, but do not know, that a spirit is therein. Once they leave the house out of fear, but they come back home after a long march.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I'm really curious what the sentence "The German commander was a good boy" means. (Sounds like a mnemonic device for remembering something else.)

Possibly Huset (House), a Norwegian movie from 2016.
Synopsis: 

Two German soldiers has taken a Norwegian soldier as prisoner, during one of the cold Scandianvian winter nights during WW2. They are thankful that they find a lonely house out in the wilderness, but the houses aren't that cozy after all.

Trailer:



